# Can AD users that are set to "User Cannot Change Password" log in after changing password complexity?

Tags: active-directory

I used group policy to bump the password length from 8 to 12 characters on the domain.  User accounts that have the following option set are not able to log in.

```
User cannot change password
```

From what I'm aware of, this length change should only affect users that reset their password or have an expired account.  Does the change immediately affect accounts that have the **User cannot change password** option set and don't meet requirements?

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question.  Due to the fact existing user's passwords, do not match the new password complexity rules, they are unable to log into those accounts.  I would imagine users with `User cannot change password` likely have passwords that also violate the password expiration rules.

Comment: I'm wanting to verify if this is something that comes into play only when that option is used in Active Directory.  I know that in normal conditions, users can log in even when their current password doesn't meet the complexity rules.

Comment: This is something you can and should test yourself. Create a test GP and apply it to a test account and adjust the settings until you figure this out. We expect people to do the minimum necessary self effort here. Please do this

Comment: I'm actually doing this as I speak. I just thought it may be something that is known.  I've searched around and couldn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: @KadeWilliams - This leads to the confusion of your question.  Do you actually have accounts configured, where the password to that account cannot be changed, and are they unable to log into those accounts after you made the change?  If you have already made this change, and the accounts are NOT able to login, we need to know that is the case.

Comment: A few accounts were configured years ago to never expire and they were also set so that the user cannot change the password.  I've recently bumped up the password length requirements on the domain.  It was reported that these users were now not able to log in due to password complexity requirements.  I just tested this on my home lab and I was able to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexity is only checked at time of password change. Often, this is also the only time when the domain controller *has* your password in clear text.

User passwords in AD are stored hashed, and not revealed to the DCs even during login. It is not possible for the DCs to evaluate password complexity when they can't see the actual password.

*(Only "simple bind" via LDAP is an exception, but it's rare enough that no enforcement is done at that point either.)*

There is no client-side enforcement of password complexity as it would be inconsistent (e.g. Windows could enforce it but various other Kerberos implementations would not).